# Two dialog boxes at once in bash script

Tags: bash

I have my bash dialog --menu box acting nicely, but i do need second one when i choose particular option like "change user". I want that "user list" --menu dialog box to open on top of the first one(which will be in background, but won't disappear completely) with specific coordinates.

Is that possible?

regards
kasper

Comment: A solution that works for this was provided in this U&L Q&A: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/156665/how-to-run-the-dialog-command-with-proccess

Answer (score 3):

Chain the two with `--and-widget`:

```
dialog --menu "menu 1"  ........  --and-widget --begin $x $y --menu "menu 2" .......
```

Menu 1 will show and once you press enter it will remain in place while menu 2 will show and take control (like a new "popup window").

Comment: Ok, that helped a bit, but what if i want to insert a case statement between? Like i want the content of the second window to depend of the option chosen in first menu? Choosing User option in 1 will show user list in 2 but choosing something else in 1 will bring something else in 2. I hope you know what i'm talking about :).

Comment: I don't think that's possible... I mean, you have the --file option (and you read what dialog to display from that file after the first dialog exists). But all you can write from a menu dialog is the "tag" and that's not very useful useful.